# How to do CRUD operations on a firestore DB from a cloud function? (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I use a cloud function as a webhook receiver, so every time I get a webhook I want to update firestore with some data for example. I don't get how to use firestore in my clound function.

I tried this:

```
      const admin = require("firebase-admin");
      ...
      
      admin.initializeApp();

      res.send(admin.database().ref("/tmp_list/1uMW9ED3YGMfERHZiKJc").get());
```

All do not seem to be able to initilise this. I also tried:

```
 admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import-the-required-modules-and-initialize-an-app), the following should do the trick:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

---

Then, to interact with the Realtime Database in an HTTPS Cloud Function you should do along the following lines:

```js
exports.date = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const db = admin.database();

  const dataSnapshot = await db.ref("tmp_list/1uMW9ED3YGMfERHZiKJc").get();

  const data = dataSnapshot.val();

  // ... 

  res.send(data);
});
```

---

Since you tagged your question as `google-cloud-firestore`, note that in order to interact with Firestore in an HTTPS Cloud Function you should do as follows:

```js
exports.date = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const db = admin.firestore();

  const docSnapshot = await db.doc("tmp_list/1uMW9ED3YGMfERHZiKJc").get();

  const data = docSnapshot.data();

  // ... 

  res.send(...)
});
```

I recommend you watch the following official [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&feature=youtu.be).